# Andengine Sprites array IndexoutofboundException

Tags: arrays, andengine, sprite, indexoutofboundsexception

I am developing a game and having problem in the following code.

```
        for(intReps = 0; intReps <=9; intReps++)
        {
     final Path path = new Path(2).to(sprBalls[intReps].getX(), sprBalls[intReps].getY()).to(sprBalls[intReps].getX(), -50);
//          sprBalls[intReps].registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
        final Path path1 = new Path(2).to(fly[intReps].getX(), fly[intReps].getY()+10).to(fly[intReps].getX(), -50);
        sprBalls[intReps].registerEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPathStarted(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                IEntity pEntity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPathWaypointStarted(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPathWaypointFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPathFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                IEntity pEntity) {
            Log.e("Msg","intReps : "+intReps); // Output is 10
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              mScene.detachChild(pEntity);
                sprBalls[intReps].detachSelf();  // Error on this line.
//              pEntity.detachSelf();
//              sprBalls[intReps].dispose();
        }
        }, EaseSineInOut.getInstance()));
}
```

Array's length is 10. I get IndexOutOfBoundException on the line with error (sprBalls[intReps].detachSelf();)
I am running the loop from 0 to 9 but on printing the value of intReps it shows 10 that is why it generates the error. I don't understand how to clear this problem. I wan't to create an array of sprites with 10 sprites in it and want to move them from one end to other and upon path finished I want them to get cleared from memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove your entities, using update thread:

```
            /* Removing entities can only be done safely on the UpdateThread.
             * Doing it while updating/drawing can
             * cause an exception with a suddenly missing entity.
             * Alternatively, there is a possibility to run the TouchEvents on the UpdateThread by default, by doing:
             * engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
             * when creating the Engine in onLoadEngine(); */
            this.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            /* Now it is save to remove the entity! */
                            yourEntity.detachSelf()
                    }
            });
```

Comment: Got it, but my problem is that when i refer to the entity (sprite), the array index is more than what it is supposed to be. I created array of 10 sprites but when i try to remove the entity the index is 10 (that refers to 11th sprite which doesn't exist).

Comment: I do not know if I understood you right, but basic thing is, that array starts from 0, so first sprite got index 0, second 1, third 2 and so on

Comment: Thanks Matim for your response but I solved the problem by replacing sprBalls[intReps].detachSelf() with pEntity.getParent().detachSelf();